# How to read value of input field using PhoneJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, phonejs

Here is my HTML :

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'home', title: 'Home' } " >
<div class="home-view"  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >

    <input data-bind="dxTextBox: { value: username }" />
    <input data-bind="dxTextBox: { value: password }" />
    <div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Login', clickAction: validateLogin }"></div>
      </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript Controller

```
MyApp.home = function (params) {

var viewModel = {

    username: ko.observable(''),
    password: ko.observable(''),

    validateLogin : function ()
    {
        console.log(this.username());
        userNameTxt = this.username();
        alert(this.username());
    }
};

return viewModel;
```

};

The value of text fields is not getting retireved. Blank message is being alerted.

Answer (score 1):

just change in alert "this" to "viewModel". like belo

```
MyApp.home = function (params) {

var viewModel = {

    username: ko.observable(''),
    password: ko.observable(''),

    validateLogin : function ()
    {
        console.log(this.username());
        userNameTxt = this.username();
        alert(viewModel.username());
    }
};

return viewModel;

};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
userName: {
        value: ko.observable(""),
        valueUpdateEvent: 'keyup search',
        placeholder: "Username",

    },
    password: {
        value: ko.observable(""),
        mode: 'password',
        placeholder: "type a password",
        valueUpdateEvent: 'keyup search',
    },
```

check it

Comment: Please add some explanation!